# Devil teaching a companion to use ayatul kursi against shayateen

Tags: hadith-interpretation, shaitan, jinn, fitrah

A devil used to visit and steal from baytul maal of muslims. When he was caught for 3rd consecutive night he taught the companion Abu hurayrah to recite ayatul kursi for protection from shayateen.

https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1020

My question is how did the devil come to know that a Muslim needs to recite ayatul kursi for protection? Is this report similar to one where ruqyah was recited for scorpion bite?

https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5736

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you and your family are doing well. We have to understand the same way a human can learn and know about haram does not mean he will use it or do haram. I know what wine is but I do not drink it. Similarly the shaytani jinn knew about ayatul kursi and its power. Morever the Quran is not just meant as a message but it has its powers/benefits throughout creation. It can affect invisible beings (ie. evil jinns) as well. One example is found in Surah Hashr (#59) verse 21.

> If We had sent down this Qur’ān upon a mountain, you would have seen it humbled and splitting from fear of ALLAAH. And these examples We present to the people that perhaps they will give thought.

Regarding the ruqyah for the scorpion bite that was something the companion (peace and blessings be upon him) learned from his own experience. Like someone who reads a verse or chapter from the Quraan and they experience something (healing, wealth, etc.) by reciting it.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.